# Customized Static TableView with Storyboard - cell background

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, customization

I am using storyboard to great a static tableview.
All works well!

Now I want to customize the table view cell.

So I add a tableViewController and connect it to the storyboard view.
Here is the code I am using to customize:

```
-- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];

    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = color;

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = color;

    cell.backgroundView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbackground.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbackground_down.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

    return cell;
}
```

But if I now run the app, the table view is empty and there is no custom background...

Can some help me? :=)

Laurenz

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to set cells for your `tableview:static` cells & dynamic prototypes. In fact,for static cell mode, you can set the cell's background color directly in IB.

If you want to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to customize your cell, you should implement all the non optional methods like:`numberOfRowsInSection` `cellForRowAtIndexPath`